# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Foreign Key Object set to some default object with id 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Having a bit of a problem with MVC4 and code first EF6 with foreign keys when creating a new object.

I've got 2 models (Job and JobItem) with JobItem having JobID as a foreign key relationship to ID on the Job model.

When inserting into JobItem, the ModelState reports that it is not valid and an error returned claiming that another field on the Job model is required. The code accesses the JobID property of the JobItem model (which is selected by the user on the form) but it seems that EF is creating a Job object with an id of 0 and populating it with some default values.

The error being returned from the ModelState is that the Billing currency field is required. Billing Currency is a required field on the Job model.

I could set the Job object and clear the ModelState but this wouldn't be a great idea as it would hide any other issues.

[image: job-object]

JobItem Model

```
[Display(Name = "Job number")]
[Required]
[ForeignKey("Job")]
public Int64 JobID { get; set; }
public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
```

JobItem Edit View

```
<div class="csam-section-block">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model.JobID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @if (@Model.Model.Job == null)
            {
                @Html.TextBox("Model.Job.Number", String.Empty,  new { @class = "csam-change-field" })
            }
            else
            {                    
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Model.Job.Number, new {@class="csam-change-field"})
            }
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Model.JobID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model.JobID)
        </div>
        <div class="csam-lookup-section">
            <input type="button" class="tbl_lookup_btn, csam-lookup-button" name='Job' value='Job,JobID' />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Update 1: Showing ModelState error
[image: ModelState Error]

As Alan noted below, the ModelState is invalid immediately when entering the SubmitForm controller action.

Comment: Please post your actual controller code. All you're showing in the screenshot is the unified POST action that then shoots off the view model to some other action method (hugely bad idea, BTW). The problem likely lies in that transition, but there's no code represented for that.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I'm also working on this project.  The problem is immediately there in the first SubmitForm controller action because the ModelState immediately thinks there is a problem with the related Job model. Even if the Job property got set manually the ModelState will still have the error in it from initial binding. This is the problem that needs solved, not the next controller action it is handed off to.

Could you elaborate on why a unified action which hands off to others is a bad idea?  We did this because we've built a framework so this is coded once rather than for every controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working with the OP on this.  It turned out to be a problem in the Job model.  The CurrencyID on the job was causing a ModelState error which was very strange because it wasn't even being shown in the view.  On closer inspection in the model there was an inconsistency where the CurrencyID was marked as an int64? but had the Required attribute.  It was indeed a required field so I changed it to Int64 and it works fine.